# Swift extension that conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am having trouble creating an extension in Swift that conforms to a protocol.

In Objective-C I could create a category that conformed to a protocol:

*SomeProtocol.h*

```
@protocol SomeProtocol
...
@end
```

*UIView+CategoryName*

```
#import SomeProtocol.h
@interface UIView (CategoryName) <SomeProtocol>
...
@end
```

I am trying to achieve the same with a Swift Extension

*SomeProtocol.swift*

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    ...
}
```

*UIView Extension*

```
import UIKit
extension UIView : SomeProtocol {
...
}
```

I receive the following compiler error:

> Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'SomeProtocol'

Comment: did you implement the methods in the protocol?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please double check in your extension that you've implemented all of the methods defined in the protocol.   If function a is not implemented, then one will get the compiler error that you listed.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func a()
}

extension UIView : SomeProtocol {
    func a() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
//**Create a Protocol:**

protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    func adjust()-> String
}


//**Create a simple Class:** 

class SimpleClass {

}

//**Create an extension:**

extension SimpleClass: ExampleProtocol {

    var simpleDescription: String {

    return "The number \(self)"
    }

    func adjust()-> String {

    return "Extension that conforms to a protocol"

    }


}

var obj = SimpleClass() //Create an instance of a class

println(obj.adjust()) //Access and print the method of extension using class instance(obj)
```

**Result: Extension that conforms to a protocol**

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Can you please explain how to confirm if var simpleDescription: String { get set } property.

Comment: @RajeshKumar `var simpleDescription: String {
        get { return "The number \(self)"}
        set(desc) { self.simpleDescription = desc}
    }`